# updating sencha touch 2 android app

Tags: android, web-applications, sencha-touch-2, google-play

I am trying to submit a update to the google play store for my sencha touch 2 app.

the following is my packager.json file.

```
{
    "applicationName":"DBS",
    "applicationId":"com.keshav.dbs",
    "versionCode":"2",
    "versionString":"1.0.1",
    "iconName":"ic_launcher.png",
    "inputPath":"./build/package/Android",
    "outputPath":"./build/native/Android",
    "configuration":"Release",
    "platform":"Android",
    "deviceType":"Universal",
    "certificatePath":"/Developer/Android-Keystore/myAndroidKeyStore",
    "certificateAlias":"myandroidkey",
    "certificatePassword":"<password>",
    "sdkPath":"/Developer/sdks/android-sdk-macosx",
    "androidAPILevel":"16",
    "orientations": [
        "portrait"
    ]
}
```

I run the following command

```
sencha package run packager.json
```

this creates the apk file however when i try to upload the new apk i get a message saying the versonCode 1 is already in use.

The instruction of packaging on Senchas website dont include the `"versionCode"` property I added that my self

Does anyone know how to change the version code for sencha app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well here it is ...

After looking around the internet i found this approach works....

After Sencah creates the package use [apktool](http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/) to un-package the apk then edit the AndroidManifest.xml and package it up again with apktool.

Note when you re-package the app tit will be unsigned so you will have to sign it again for it install on peoples devices

Answer (score 1):

I was able to edit platforms/cordova/android/AndroidManifest.xml and update the android:versionCode, then run sencha app build native

It built the new APK (signed, based on my config) and it was accepted by the Google Play store.

Much easier than un-packaging and repackaging.